# Show dynamic additional cells in main cell

Tags: swift, uitableview

I need to show results of quiz which contains question text label and dynamic number of answers (Label + UIImage).

Which way of doing it is the best? Adding a tableview inside tableview? Or anything else?

Comment: Please elaborate your question, make it a bit more understandable.

Comment: @Ashik I've made some changes, hope it became more understandable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add a dynamic `UITableView` with a prototype section and a cell in a `UIViewController` each section has the question title in it and inside each section cell put a `UIimageView` & `UILabel`for the different answers.

Don't forget your delegates and datasources plus create a `UITableViewCell` swift file to add the `IBOutlets` of the `UIImageView` & the `UILabel`. If you need a sample code i can provide you with one if you didn't really understood what i mean. But if you played with tabelViews before you will be able to do it easily.

Comment: @sayhello ok will prepare something for you